# seaborn barplot TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, seaborn

This is the info for my dataset:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 550068 entries, 0 to 550067
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count   Dtype   
---  ------      --------------   -----   
 0   ID          550068 non-null  int64   
 1   pID         550068 non-null  object  
 2   Gender      550068 non-null  category
 3   Age         550068 non-null  category
 4   Occupation  550068 non-null  category
 5   City        550068 non-null  category
 6   Years       550068 non-null  int64   
 7   Married     550068 non-null  category
 8   pCat1       550068 non-null  category
 9   pCat2       376430 non-null  category
 10  pCat3       166821 non-null  category
 11  Purchase    550068 non-null  int64   
dtypes: category(8), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 18.9+ MB
```

I am trying to plot a bar chart between City and Purchase using seaborn:

```
sns.barplot(data = train_df, x = "City", y = "Purchase")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance.

NOTE: I am using Anaconda Spyder 4.0 IDE and python 3.7

Comment: Maybe you have a 32-bit version of numpy installed? You could try converting the 'int64' columns to 'int32' provided the numbers are small enough.

Comment: I tried that but it's showing the same error. I used the following code for conversion: ``` train_df.Purchase = train_df.Purchase.astype('int32')```